# mysql, distinct and by most recent

Tags: mysql

I'm using query:

```
SELECT distinct player, date, (health_base + mana_base * 2) as vit FROM dadb.player_attributes order by  vit desc
```

and getting the following results:

```
# player       date,                   vit
-----------------------------------------------
'Greenslade', '2016-01-12 14:05:03',  '1208252'
'Greenslade', '2016-01-12 14:05:04',  '1208252'
'Greenslade', '2016-01-12 14:07:46',  '1208252'
'Greenslade', '2016-01-12 14:07:47',  '1208252'
'Pheresis',   '2016-01-12 13:45:54',  '924164'
'Pheresis',   '2016-01-12 13:45:55',  '924164'
'Pheresis',   '2016-01-12 13:48:55',  '924164'
'Pheresis',   '2016-01-12 13:48:56',  '924164'
'Pheresis',   '2016-01-12 13:48:57',  '924164'
'Pheresis',   '2016-01-12 14:04:00',  '924164'
'Pheresis',   '2016-01-12 14:04:01',  '924164'
```

How can I make it so my sql query returns only one player, date, vit;
for the each distinct player with the most recent date?

I want my output to be:

```
# player       date,                   vit
-----------------------------------------------
'Greenslade', '2016-01-12 14:07:47',  '1208252'
'Pheresis',   '2016-01-12 14:04:01',  '924164'
```

how can i do it?

Comment: **select distinct** considers all values in a row, if any of those values is different in any way at all to some other row, then it is distinct. that is all it does. to reduce the number of rows requires grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need aggregation:

```
select player, max(date), max(health_base + mana_base * 2) as vit
from t
group by player
order by vit desc;
```

Comment: I understand the concept of `MAX()` by reading your answer ... +1